# WSO2: swagger.yaml 404 (Not Found)

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

I cloned wso2 api manager from this url: [apim](https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps)
when I wanted to compile the code this error appeared in chrome:

//localhost:8084/api/am/devportal/v3/swagger.yaml 404 (Not Found)

How can I solve this problem?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Whats the APIM version you are using? Why do you need to clone this repo? Are you trying to do some customizations to the UI?

Comment: Yes, I want to customize the UI. The version is 4.1.0

Comment: How can I solve this error? I tried to change swagger ui version but, it didn't work

Comment: Can you access Publisher? This error means that REST API details cannot be pulled from the APIM server to the UI server.

Comment: No, I want to customize the Devportal, also the Publisher has its own error and I don't want to deal with that. But the publisher in "localhost:9443" is OK.

Comment: Shouldn't be this url instead of that: /localhost:9443/api/am/devportal/v3/swagger.yaml

Comment: I think it shouldn't be like this: /localhost:8084/api/am/devportal/v3/swagger.yaml

Comment: If you are running the UI in dev mode its run separately from the server. https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps/tree/4.1.0#run-in-dev-mode. Otherwise you need to changes here and build the whole product (product-apim)

Comment: I've done that, but the error hasn't gone.

Comment: There is somthing wrong while creating swagger.yaml. Please give a solution for that.

Comment: Instead of the 4.1.0 branch can you try to checkout to v9.0.311 tag and build?

Comment: Still error. With which version of product should I have run?